# Как можно профилировать свой код в windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, оптимизация, профилирование

Хочу научится профилировать код в PyCharm в windows 7. Но никак немогу открыть фалы .prof в виндовс. Насколько я понял все средства профилирования для линукс.
Как можно открыть файл .prof для нормального обзора кода так сказать.
Вот этот код хочу ускорить: задание-
надо вычислить сумму биномиальных коэффициентов на заданной диагонали. Сумма на диагонали 0 равна 8 ( S (7, 0), 7 - номер строки, в которой мы начинаем, 0 - номер диагонали). Точно так же S (7, 1) равно 28, S (7, 2) равно 56.
Надо написать программу, которая вычисляет S (n, p), где n - это линия, где мы начинаем, а p - число диагонали.
Вот код:

```
def diagonal(n, k):    
    def pow_binomial(n, k):
        def eratosthenes(N):
            simp = [2]
            nonsimp = set()
            for i in range(3, N + 1, 2):
                if i not in nonsimp:
                    nonsimp |= {j for j in range(i * i, N + 1, 2 * i)}
                    simp.append(i)
            return simp

        def calc_pow_in_factorial(a, p):
            res = 0
            while a > 0:
                a //= p
                res += a
            return res

    simple = eratosthenes(n + 1)
    n_fact_pows = {p: calc_pow_in_factorial(n, p) for p in simple}
    k_fact_pows = {p: calc_pow_in_factorial(k, p) for p in simple}
    nmk_fact_pows = {p: calc_pow_in_factorial(n - k, p) for p in simple}
    ans = 1
    for p in simple:
        ans *= p ** (n_fact_pows[p] - k_fact_pows[p] - nmk_fact_pows[p])
    return ans

out = 0
while n > 0:
    f = n - k
    out += (round(pow_binomial(n, f)))
    n -= 1
return out
```

Начинает тормозить если запустить функцию с такими аргументами-n=1921, k=5

Answer (score 0):

```
import cProfile
....
def profile(func):
    """Decorator for run function profile"""

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        profile_filename = func.__name__ + '.prof'
        profiler = cProfile.Profile()
        result = profiler.runcall(func, *args, **kwargs)
        profiler.dump_stats(profile_filename)
        return result

    return wrapper
...
@profile
def ТвояГлавнаяФункцияИлиТОЧтоНадоПрофилировать():
    блаБлаБла
    f()
    ff()
...
```

Используем [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org)

Если вызывает вопрос gprof2dot, то берем его [здесь](https://pypi.org/project/gprof2dot/)

gprof2dot.exe -o c:\<твой путь>\s.res -f pstats c:\<твой путь>\test_cmu.prof

c:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe -Tpng -Tps c:\<твой путь>\s.res -o c:\<твой путь>\test_cmu.png

Вот пример моего поиска .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Кроме того, можем получить статистику

```
>>> import pstats
>>> p = pstats.Stats('<твой путь к файлу статистики>\<какой то там>.prof')
>>> p.sort_stats('calls').print_stats()
```

Comment: Спасибо, проверю позже.